# ESLint not working: VSCode warning: "ESLint is disabled since its execution has not been approved or denied yet"

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

My VS Code has the ES Lint plugin installed and has, all of a sudden, stopped working. All I can see is a yellow squiggly at the first line of my files, which shows the message: "*ESLint is disabled since its execution has not been approved or denied yet*". Goes without saying, ESLint no more does what it should do. Does nothing in fact.

Though this isn't really work-stopper kind of issue, it sure is a bit annoying, having been used to coding with ESLint by my side always.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Found the solution. And it's rather simple. Thanks to [this site](https://www.programmersought.com/article/39816125321/), found the solution that fixed my problem. Gereon too has mentioned it rightly in his comment.

Turns out I had somehow disabled the extension in VSCode. All I had to do was enable it. There's an icon at the bottom right corner that says ESLint, and if disabled, it's shown with a red icon. All that I had to do was click on it, and allow it to be enabled everywhere in the dialog that was shown soon after.

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Eslint is disabled in the right-bottom part of vs code. Just enable it. I hope it will solve the problem.

[image: Eslint is disabled in the right-bottom part of vs code. Just enable it. I hope it will solve the problem.]

Answer (score 2):

There should be an icon you can click to see the approval dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that it is because of a change in the default done in the last version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this way. If you have still any problem

[image]